# Why would larger files be triggering a 500 error when uploading PDFs through PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload

When I upload a pdf file of 30MB it shows a 500 error, but if I upload a 10MB file it is successful.

I have set:

```
max_input_time=300
post_max_size=128M
upload_max_filesize=128M
```

What could be causing this error?

Comment: Every 500 error leaves an entry in the `error.log` file. There should be a more verbose error message there

Comment: @Pekka: I had no permissions to access error.log in server

Comment: What is your script doing with the PDF file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the following in your PHP.ini and see

```
memory_limit=128M
upload_max_filesize=128M  
post_max_size=128M
max_input_time=3000  
max_execution_time=3000 
memory_limit=128M
```

Comment: All the `max_` settings regarding upload and input times are pointless to set in a script, since the upload/input is already finished by the time the script is run.

Answer (score 0):

Maby your server timeout settings are too fast. Default setting is (i believe) 30 seconds, it depends on your connection if you can upload your file in 30 seconds or not, so the 10MB is within the 30seconds and the 30MB gives you a time out.

You can set the timeout limit in your PHP.ini or try it in PHP self (Not all servers accept that).
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Hope it helps
You can test it by hitting your upload button and count 30 seconds if your error comes within 30 seconds something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

include the following in the top of your page and try uploading

```
ini_set("memory_limit","256M");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) configuration option. And, may be it would be better if you enable errors on this page using

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

so PHP errors would be displayed on page, not a server error.